# Can I use my Java code to develop an Android app?

Tags: java, android, api, development-environment

I'm in the early midst of making a game with Java, and would eventually like to turn it into an android application.

All the developer technical stuff aside, will the code itself remain the same, or will I have to rework the better part of it?

Thanks in advance for the feedback

Comment: If you follow a layered architecture, you will not need much effort. You would only need to change the UI layer as per Android

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes,you can do like that where your rendering part need to be changed if you want to use it in android. So the better option is use some framework to port your code to work in Android system as well. [LibGdx](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/) is such a kind of framework where you can develop and test your application in stand alone mode and without changing your code, you can run it in `Android` as well. Please refer `LibGDX` site for more information

Comment: excellent - if I use libGDX as you recommend, do I have to worry as much about which version of android to develop for?

Comment: @Jona, if you use libgdx,  it will work in latest version of Android as well unless your game wants to use only latest version. But caveat here is you need to test in diff version for look and feel and performance

Comment: I want my game (which is very simple) to work on as many versions as possible, so if I choose the latest version will it automatically be compatible with the previous versions? thanks very much for your help

Comment: you can target your game in Android 2.0 or 2.2 and that will allow to work your game in higer versions as well. Nothing to worry. Only thing you need to take care is the above aspects

Answer (score 2):

Android code is java, so yes!

You'll have to change some stuff. For instance, if you're using swing to show stuff on the screen, you'll have to change it to use the android API; but the core of the code should remain the same.

I remember doing my very first videogame in java. Porting it to android only required me to modify little.